# Simple queue and multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to process a lot of files. I wrote simple Java program that does the job, but it is too slow.

I need more than 1 working thread.

Im totally new with Java and Java multithreading.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    // some queue here?

    for (int i = 1; i < 8000000; i++)
    {
        processId(i);
    }
}

public static void processId(int id)
{
    try 
    {
        // do work
        System.out.println("Im working on: " + Integer.toString(id));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // do something with errors
        System.out.println("Error while working on: " + Integer.toString(id));
    }

}
```

**How can I add simple queue with 8 threads?**

Comment: Perhaps you want to try an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking.   Perhaps start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into Executors.

You can create a thread pool of 8 threads using:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
```

Then submit your tasks inside your loop the following way:

```
final int finalId = i; // final is necessary to be enclosed in lambda
executor.submit(() -> processId(finalId));
```

Or prior to java 8:

```
final int temp = i; // final is necessary to be enclosed in anonymous class
executor.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        processId(finalId);
    }
});
```

Don't forget to shutdown the thread pool when not needed anymore, as mentioned [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Here is an example from the doc:

```
private void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
    pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    try {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
        if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
            if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        pool.shutdownNow();
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, this is sooo simple!

Comment: It will create a lot of runnable objects though :-/ but I can't think of a better and simple way from the top of my head

Comment: I have enough memory :) This is exatly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into `ExecutorService`. This will make multithreading easy. An example:

Main code:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
for (int i = 1; i < 8000000; i++) {
    pool.submit(new intProcessingTask(i));
}
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// all tasks have now finished (unless an exception is thrown above)
```

`intProcessingTask` code:

```
private static class DownloadTask implements Runnable {
    private int id;

    public DownloadTask(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Im working on: " + Integer.toString(id));
    }
}
```

This is slightly longer than the the other answer, but does pretty much the same thing, and works on Java 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways in Java for processing mulithreading. Base on your question that you need a queue, I think the most simple version is use Java `ExecutorService`. You can see this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // creating a thread pool with maximum thread will be 8
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
            for (int i = 0; i < 8000000; i++) {
                final int threadId = i;
                executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        processId(threadId);

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

`ExecutorService` has some methods:

1. execute(Runnable)
2. submit(Runnable)
3. submit(Callable)
4. invokeAny(...)
5. invokeAll(...)

I recommend you view this link: [ExecutorService tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) for clear explanation.

Hope this help :)